# The definition of Gaussian State

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, quantum-states

Could you clarify to me what is a Gaussian state? I know what is a Gaussian function and Gaussian distribution, but I don't know how to respond to other when they ask me to provide the definition of a Gaussian state.

Thank you.

Comment: On $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, $\psi(x)=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{\pi})^d}e^{-\lvert x\rvert^2}$ is a normalized gaussian state (vector of the Hilbert space).

Comment: @TBBT Are you referring to QFT or QM?

Comment: I am referring to G.S in Quantum Information Processing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A Gaussian state is a ground or thermal state of a (bosonic or fermionic) Hamiltonian which is quadratic in the creation and annihiliation operators.  Those states are fully characterized by expectation values of quadratic operators, and thus $4N^2$ parameters for $N$ fermions or bosons.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting answer. Could you provide a reference on the mathematical proof of: "Gaussian states are fully characterized by expectation values of quadratic operators"? Since you mention $4N^2$ parameters (not $N^2$), I think you allow "BCS terms" like $\rho =e^{-C a^\dagger a^\dagger + h.c.}$. I am curious on the extension of the above statement when BCS terms are present.

Comment: @eigenvalue You can really take this as a definition of Gaussian states (if you say *how* they are determined by two-point correlations). Only if you give me a *different* definition there is something to prove.

Comment: My definition of the Gaussian states is the density matrix of the form $\rho \sim e^{-H_{ij} a^\dagger_i a_j + (K_{ij} a^\dagger_i a^\dagger_j + h.c.)}$.

Comment: @eigenvalue This looks like a separate question, rather than sth. which should be answered in a comment.

Comment: All coherent states are Gaussian states. They are neither thermal states, nor are they ground states, apart from the vacuum states. The same applies for squeezed states.

Comment: @flippiefanus 
Of course coherent and squeezed states are ground states of a suitable Hamiltonian. *Any* pure state is the ground state of some Hamiltonian.

Comment: For instance, $|\alpha\rangle$ is the ground state of, for example, $H=(a-\alpha)^\dagger(a-\alpha)$, as this operator is non-negative (i.e. its smallest eigenvalue is 0) and  $|\alpha\rangle$ has expectation value 0. You can now apply a squeezing transformation to $|\alpha\rangle$, and the inverse transformation to $H$, and will obtain a Hamiltonian for the corresponding squeezed coherent state.

Comment: OK, it was not clear from your answer that one needs to construct a special Hamiltonian for each and every state. Rather laborious way to define Gaussian states, don't you think? There are simpler definitions. BTW, what is the physical scenario where one would have such a Hamiltonian?

Answer (score 14):

The most general description of a quantum system is given by a density matrix $\rho$. It has dimensions of $N \times N$, where $N$ is the number of degrees of freedom of the system: 2 for a 2 level quantum system (qubit), 3 for 3-level etc. But often we deal with the systems that have infinite number of degrees of freedom. Such systems are quantum harmonic oscillators, modes of light and other systems with a certain Hamiltonian as was pointed out in a previous answer. The density matrix approach is not the most convenient for such systems as you have to deal with infinite matrices and moreover if you consider a composite system $\rho^{AB}=\rho^{A} \otimes \rho^{B}$, with tensor products of those. But one can apply a transformation:

$\chi(\xi,\xi^*) = Tr[D(\xi,\xi^*) \rho]$

where $D(\xi,\xi^*) = \exp[\xi \hat{a}^{\dagger} - \xi^* \hat{a}] $ is a [displacement operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_operator). This transformation maps the space of the $\rho^{\otimes M}$ density matrices to a space of $2M$ variable functions ($\xi$ and $\hat{a}$ are vectors when $M>1$). $\chi$ is called a [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiprobability_distribution) and the states for which it is Gaussian are obviously called Gaussian. The most general Gaussian state is a displaced thermal squeezed state.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest definition is "Gaussian state are the states whose [Wigner function is a Gaussian function](https://browse.arxiv.org/pdf/1111.0786.pdf)"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).